# código da página PHP aparecendo ao clicar no botão submit do formulário

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-insert

Na minha página html eu tenho o seguinte formulário:

```html
<form method="POST" action="index.php" class="header">
    
    <label for="km_tdo" id="lbTdo">KM troca de óleo:</label><input class="text-input" type="text" name="km_tdo" id="km_tdo" autofocus data-rule-required="true"/><button type="button" onclick="estadoAtual()">Ok</button><div class="situacao km_trocadeoleo" id="km_trocadeoleo"></div><br>
    
    <label for="km_alin" id="lbAlinhamento">KM alinhamento:</label><input class="text-input" type="text" name="km_alin" id="km_alin" data-rule-required="true"/><button type="button" onclick="estadoAtualAlinhamento()">Ok</button><div class="situacao km_alinhamento" id="km_alinhamento"></div><br>
    
    <label for="revisao" id="lbRevisao">Revisão:</label><input class="text-input" type="text" name="revisao" id="revisao" data-rule-required="true"/><button type="button" onclick="estadoAtualRevisao()">Ok</button><div class="situacao result_revisao" id="km_revisao"><br>
    </div><br>
    
    <label for="last_km_abastecimento" id="lbKmAbastecimento">KM do abastec..:</label><input class="text-input" type="text" name="last_km_abastecimento" id="last_km_abastecimento" data-rule-required="true"/>
    
    <label for="dt_lancamento_combustivel" id="lbDataAbastecimento">Data abastec..:</label><input type="date" class="text-input text-input-data" name="dt_lancamento_combustivel" id="dt_lancamento_combustivel"><br>
    
    <label for="placa_do_veiculo" id="lbPlacaVeiculo">Placa:</label>
    <select name="placa_do_veiculo" id="placa_do_veiculo">
      <option value="MSS-1370">MSS-1370</option>
      <option value="MPK-6473">MPK-6473</option>
      <option value="MTO-1121">MTO-1121</option>
    </select>
    <label for="tipo_de_servico" id="lbTipoServico">Serviço:</label>
    <select name="tipo_de_servico" id="tipo_de_servico" class="list-menu">
      <option value="1">Abastecimento</option>
      <option value="2">Alinhamento</option>
      <option value="3">Revisão</option>
      <option value="4">Troca de óleo</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn_gravar_dados btn_azul">Registrar</button>
  </form>
```

Após clicar no botão registrar é carregado uma página (na mesma guia) exibindo o conteúdo do meu index.php, esse aqui:

```
<?php
  include("conexao.php");

  $km_troca_de_oleo = $_POST['km_tdo'];
  $km_alinhamento = $_POST['km_alin'];
  $km_revisao = $_POST['revisao'];
  $km_abastecimento = $_POST['last_km_abastecimento'];
  $data_abastecimento = $_POST['dt_lancamento_combustivel'];
  $placa = $_POST['placa_do_veiculo'];
  $tipo_de_servico = $_POST['tipo_de_servico'];

  // criando conexão
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  // checando conexão
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  //string de inserção
  $sqlInsertInto = "INSERT INTO veiculo (placa, km_abastecimento, data_abastecimento, km_troca_de_oleo, km_alinhamento, km_revisao)
   VALUES ('$placa','$km_abastecimento','$data_abastecimento','$km_troca_de_oleo','$km_alinhamento','$km_revisao')";

  //verifico se houve sucesso na tentativa de persistir os dados no banco
  if ($conn->query($sqlInsertInto) === TRUE) {
    echo "Dados cadastrados com sucesso!";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }

  //encerro a conexão com o banco de dados
  $conn->close();
?>
```

conteúdo do meu arquivo conexão.php:

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = " ";
  $dbname = "controle_de_tipo_de_servico_do_veiculo";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
?>
```

Já me disseram que poderia ser o serviço relacionado ao servidor, mas eu estou usando o XAMPP e ele subiu, porque estou com o phpmyadmim aberto.

Comment: O apache ta sendo executado no XAMPP? 
O endereço na barra do navegador ta como localhost?

Comment: Talvez o seu Apache não esteja ativado...

Comment: @Lindomar sim no XAMPP, sim localhost!

Comment: @AngeloSoares ontem estava funcionando normalmente, hoje está dando esse problema. Coloquei para criar atalho na área de trabalho quando instalei o XAMPP, porém não criou, procurei ele em todos os programas (usando windows 7) ele também não aparece. Hoje mais sedo para acessar o phpmyadmin eu tive que ir na pasta xampp salva na raiz diretório e startar por lá, o apache startei também por lá (estou com ele aberto na janela do prompt)

Answer (score 4):

É possível que você esteja abrindo o arquivo .html, ao invés de utilizar o `localhost`. Certifique-se de utilizar o caminho `localhost/[nome da pasta]/[nome do arquivo].html` no seu navegador

Answer (score 2):

Eu resolvi o problema! Vou responder aqui para deixar registrado e que novos usuários com problemas semelhantes possam testar essa hipótese.

O problema se encontra no arquivo `.php`(nome do arquivo `"index.php"`) que é chamado ao pressionar do botão registrar.

Estou usando o **wamp** e por padrão(aparentemente, não tenho certeza!) o carregamento dos arquivos que fica na pasta *www(localhost)* carrega o `index.php` primeiro. Acessando por *localhost/index.html* o `front` da aplicação era apresentada normalmente.

Sendo assim, eu alterei o nome do arquivo `index.php` para outro nome e apaguei o nome `"index.php"` na `action` do `form` e substitui pelo novo nome do arquivo. **Ex.:** `"cadastradados.php"`.

Removi a linha referente a criação da conexão(até porque ela já está contida no arquivo `conexao.php`) do `arquivo.php`(o que alteramos o nome, o antigo `"index.php"`) que é chamado após o usuário clicar no botão registrar.

Comment: Então quando você disse que aparecia o "código da página php" após o envio do formulário era o resultado do processamento desse código, não o código-fonte?

Comment: era o código fonte!

Comment: Mas se ele não processa o index.php, não deveria processar o cadastrados.php. O que deveria era processar qualquer php, independentemente do nome do arquivo. A origem do seu problema deve estar em outro lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Boa dia, 
Pode haver vários motivos para isso estar acontecendo dentre eles :

- Falha ao iniciar o servidor PHP
- Arquivo renomeado de forma errada ex: "index.php.html" parece brincadeira mas acontece muito.
- Carácter especial no meio da digitação do codigo PHP, as vezes deu um CTRL + V e acidentalmente veio junto.
- Apache com rewrite desconfigurado.

Alguns que consigo lembrar agora.

Comment: como eu faço para verificar esse último item da lista?

Comment: Esse link vai te dar um direcionamento.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-a-pilha-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-no-ubuntu-18-04-pt

já da uma geral no seu servidor e vê se as configurações estão assim.

Comment: Fique atento aos programas instalados na sua maquina por exemplo o SKYPE, que usa a mesma porta do xampp e acaba impedindo o funcionamento dele caso esteja em execução.

Answer (score 0):

Com banco de dados nunca fiz, mas fiz um formulário com envio de e-mail, e utilizei Ajax por conta do redirecionamento da página que eu não queria, e eu tive esse problema no envio que mostrava o que estava acontecendo no servidor e carregava a página. No meu caso no arquivo [send.php](https://github.com/anacvignola/BadescInternalForm/blob/master/send.php) eu coloquei isso -> `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;`. Talvez isso lhe ajude.

Comment: Eu já resolvi, mas grato pela ajuda!